# Aggregate string into Array using _.groupBy in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given:

```js
const data = [
  { user: "user1", data: "data11" },
  { user: "user1", data: "data12" },
  { user: "user1", data: "data13" },
  { user: "user2", data: "data21" },
  { user: "user2", data: "data22" }
];

const output = _(data).groupBy('user')
      .map((vals, key) => ({ 'user': key, 'data': _.take(vals, 'data')}))
      .value();

console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

How to get output like this by lodash _.groupBy :

```
const output = [{user:'user1',data:['data11','data12','data13']},
                {user:'user2',data:['data21','data22']}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah, he tried heading over to SO and asking some else to do it for him.

Comment: _(data).groupBy('user')
                .map((vals, key) => ({
                    'user': key,
                    'data': _.take(vals,'data')
                }))
                .value();

Comment: @NickParsons, I'm newer using lodash, Thanks!

Comment: @Jerry (I think my previous comment gave the incorrect output) change `_.take` with `._map` in your code and it should work

Comment: @NickParsons I have reopened. You can post an answer (Or close if you have a better duplicate target)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it. Lodash's [`_.take()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#take) method is used to slice the first *n* items from an array of items. Instead, you want to `_.map` your array of grouped objects to an array of data strings by "extracting" `data` attribute from each object. This can be done using `_.map(vals, 'data')`. See example below:

```js
const data = [
  { user: "user1", data: "data11" },
  { user: "user1", data: "data12" },
  { user: "user1", data: "data13" },
  { user: "user2", data: "data21" },
  { user: "user2", data: "data22" }
];

const output = _(data).groupBy('user')
      .map((vals, user) => ({ user, 'data': _.map(vals, 'data')})).value();

console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```